# table of contents in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking for a tutorial or sugestions on how to build table of contents in an ssrs report, something like this:

[image]

I'm almost there, the only problem is I cannot figure out how to calculate page numbers of the row in a table. Can it be done with bookmarks? or maybe a document map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible in SSRS (deriving sequential page numbers in the body section of the report), since page numbers are only valid in page headers.

However, you could use the page name property of each report object to produce section numbers, and combine this with resetting page numbers at the start of each section so that each section always begins on page *n*.1 .

So your Contents page could look something like this:

```
Table of Contents

Submission ............... 1.1

Preface .................. 2.1

Executive Summary ........ 3.1

...

Appendices

          A.  Populations and Trends ....... A.1

          B.  Land Use Data ................ B.1
...
```

Comment: Mark how can I use Page name property to produce section numbers? What expression should I use for that?

Comment: @user194076: Set the page name property to be the section number. So in the example, the page name for the Submission would be `1`, for the Preface would be `2` and so on.