# How to create table of contents in ssrs Report 2008 add page number or bookmark

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

Working on SSRS 2008 want to add the Three level of  table of contents, which is having feature of page number and it is also clickable ,if i click to link i can move to that Chapter

- Chapter 1                              (1 page)
- Chapter 1.1                        (2 page)
- ------------Chapter 1.1.1              (3 page)
- ------------Chapter 1.1.2              (3 page)
- ------------Chapter 1.1.3              (4 page)
- --- -Chapter 1.2                       (5 page)
  -Chapter 2                                (6 page)

On this if  not able to give the page number then at list want to give Book mark for the Link. So click to the Chapter 2 then it move To chapter 2
This [Post One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036466/table-of-contents-in-ssrs)  Which saying that it [Post Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431739/table-of-contents-in-ssrs-along-with-grouping)

Answer (score 2):

SSRS has in build indexing. We have to use Document map. select the cell and click to the F4 and select the Property documentMap and give your Expression